# Resize function missing from repeated field in protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Current protoc version: 25.0

I am trying to add x elements into a repeated field at once, and I thought the best way to do it was to use the [Resize](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.repeated_field/#RepeatedField.Resize.details) function. However When I try to compile the following errors emerge:

```
‘class google::protobuf::RepeatedPtrField<Elem>’ has no member named ‘Resize’; did you mean ‘size’?
```

Minimum reproducible example ( Neither function call compiles ):

```protobuf
message Elem{
    uint32 a = 1;
}
message Container{
    repeated Elem elems = 5;
}
```

```cpp
Container c;
c.mutable_elems()->Resize(5);
c.mutable_elems()->Resize(5, Elem());
```

Why might this be and is there any way to avoid boilerplate in this case?

(boilerplate like `for(int i = 0; i <5; ++i)c.add_elems();`)

Comment: `Resize()` is a member function of `RepeatedField`, not of `RepeatedPtrField`.

Comment: Oh, then Repeatedfields containing other messages would be RepeatedPtrFields, not RepeatedFields, as such they won't have the Resize function.. 

I think this answers my question

Comment: Correct, `repeated uint32 elems = 5;` would get `RepeatedField<uint32>` and have `Resize()`.

Comment: You can use `Reserve(5)` to optimize your insertions.

Comment: Would you write this into an answer, please? Then I'll be able to accept it

Comment: It was night. Now it's morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repeated Elem elems` contains a vector-like container of pointers to other repeated messages. `c.mutable_elems()` returns this container of pointers `RepeatedPtrField<Elem>`, which does not have the `Resize()` method. Having this method would have little sense, you unlikely want to fill the container with several null pointers or a same single pointer repeated in several new elements.

`RepeatedPtrField<Elem>` has the [`Reserve()`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/cpp/api-docs/google.protobuf.repeated_field/#RepeatedPtrField.Reserve.details) method, that can be used before an insertion loop for better performance:

```
Container c;
c.mutable_elems()->Reserve(5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  c.add_elem(...);  // or c.AddAllocated(...);
```